# Spring Security automatic login interception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've already developed a register and login module with Spring Security. My concern now is about how can I intercept the automatic stored login to save info in a database. I mean, when user marks "remember me", if enters into my app, automatically goes to logged-homepage but I would like to register that access in a database.

Now it's easy to do when users goes explicitly through login page, but not in the above case.

Regards,

**UPDATE:** I put some extra info:

- **security.xml**

  ```
   <http auto-config="true">
       <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/private/dashboard" />
       <remember-me key="rememberMeKey" user-service-ref="userServiceImpl" />
   </http>
   <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />
   <authentication-manager>
       <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServiceImpl">
           <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
       </authentication-provider>
   </authentication-manager>
  ```
- **userServiceImpl**

  ```
  @Service
  @Transactional
  public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  @Resource
  private UserDao userDao;

      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

          List<GrantedAuthority> AUTHORITIES = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
          String password = userDao.getUserPassword(username);

          if (password!=null) {
              userDao.registerAccess(username);
              AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_REGISTERED")); 
              return new User(username,password, AUTHORITIES);
      } else {
              throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found: " + username);
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
@Component
public class AppListener implements ApplicationListener {


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
            handleLoginEvent();
        } else if (event instanceof HttpSessionDestroyedEvent)
            handleLogoutEvent((HttpSessionDestroyedEvent) event);

    }

    private void handleLoginEvent() {
      // handle login event
    }

    private synchronized void handleLogoutEvent(HttpSessionDestroyedEvent event) {
        // handle logout event
    }

}
```

Regards,

`EDIT`

add this to web.xml

```
  <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Comment: Yeee thanks, I will try. Is it necessary to add something to security.xml/appContext.xml files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks again @Ionut but your code in my app doesn't make anything. Neither login explcitly nor remembering me nothing happens. It's strange...

Comment: hi, i've checked my code and discover that, you have something to add to web.xml , a listener which will notify you application about the event

Comment: Thanks for your time @Ionut. I've added the listener to web.xml but nothing happens one more time. I don't know if there is a problem with my login/rememberme method or... Thanks ;)

Comment: using the event listerner is the proper way to do this. using the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` implementation with rememberMe, will cause there not to be a saved request, and the user will be redirected to `home`

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options here:

- Set up your org.springframework.security.web.authentication.**AuthenticationSuccessHandler**
- Subscribe to org.springframework.security.authentication.event.**InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent** (see @Ionut answer)

**AuthenticationSuccessHandler** will work equally **for both your cases** (normal login and remember me):

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // log authentication success here for both cases
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

}
```

In your **security.xml**:

```
<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.domain.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>


<security:http ... >
    ...
    <security:form-login login-page='/login.html' authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <security:remember-me authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

</security:http>
```

Comment: Thanks for your options. I've tried first one but I can only intercept  data when users logins explcitly through login page. If user is already logged in and enters directly to "dashboard" page, the method does not run. I will try @Ionut option.

Comment: I missed that you need to set up **authentication-success-handler-ref** twice for **form-login** and for **remember-me**. Mu answer is updated.

Comment: Mmmm it doesn't still fit my purpose. I've put a System.out code but only appears when user logged in through login page... Thanks